# How to recreate the merging of gelatin

Tags: materials, shaders

I need to recreate the merging of white and colored gelatin:
[image: picture]

I presume the process could contain these steps given a mold (powdered starch) to cast the product (facedown):

1. Pour fruity colored gelatin
2. Pour white gelatin after step 1 has dried a bit

[image: picture]

Comment: Hello :). This can be easily achieved with shaders. Or are you looking for a simulation?

Comment: @JachymMichal Hello :) I'm creating one picture of such a candy, no simulation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To imitate the border, simply use a gradient as a mask between two Principled BSDF shaders.

As for the top material, glass with higher roughness works pretty well.

[image]

[image]