# Realistic Jello Material?

Tags: materials

Trying to make a jello material that looks similar to the photo. I can't get my blue to be that color, or that saturation, and I really can't figure out how to make the inside have that cool shimmer to it.

I've tried messinig with light paths and volume absorption but not much luck.

[image: Jellow]
[image: My Material]

Comment: Environment and shape is very important for the look. A cube will always look different than a piece in a spoon because the irregular shape is very distinct and the environment is important since the look depends on what is reflected and refracted.

Comment: I agree, but I can't get my color tone right, my blue is way different than that blue. So far I've had a little luck with subsurface scattering but not a ton.

Comment: You can adjust the color. There is no magic workflow for that. Adjust it until you like it. You could pick the color from the image to start, just keep in mind, the values are not the same since color in Blender is linear and the image is probably sRGB or whatever other color space. Blender image also goes through Filmic color transform before it reaches your eyes. You will have to match the colors visually.

Comment: I understand that, I'm more advanced at blender than this question sounds. I am trying to say that while using a transmission material, I cannot get ANY blue from the color wheel to look anything like the jello image. If I turn transmission off, matching it isn't as hard, but I need transmission on so that it looks clear. 

I've tried creating a new shader using fresnel+color ramp as the factor to a mix shader, but I'm not loving it even though the color is now closer.
https://imgur.com/a/3J3VrNE

Comment: My advice would be to find a reference image of what you are trying to create. At the moment you have an image of completely different thing. The irregular form of the piece in a spoon looks completely different than a whole cube with smooth sides. I was thinking of providing an answer, but I realised I would start by modelling a piece similar to the reference so I hesitated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32466/how-to-make-a-jelly-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212458/how-to-recreate-the-merging-of-gelatin https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84417/gummy-bear-and-gummy-worm-materials

Comment: I suspect the image of jello has been digitally manipulated to be "more blue" or "less red". My understanding is that in images from modern digital cameras, all sufficiently bright lights saturate to one color — typically white. However, in the image of jello, the bright specular reflections off the spoon are solid white, while the bright caustic refractions through the jello are solid cyan, so I think the red channel has been reduced in non-specular jello region of the image.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a glass material, so maybe try the *Transmission* at 1, a low *Roughness*, and pick up the color with the pipette. Also sculpt the object in order to have these bumps:

[image]

You can also fake some bumps with a *Noise Texture*:

[image]